# String formatting not working

Tags: java, string, formatting

I'm trying to use some new Java string formatting tricks, pretty basic stuff. It compiles without any error messages but won't allow me to execute the code. Could someone please explain to me why this is wrong? Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
class TestingStringFormat {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.printf("Total cost %-10d ; quantity %d\n", "ten spaces",5, 120);

        for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
        System.out.printf("%-2d: ", i,  "some text here/n", 1);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both of your `printf`s, the number of format specifiers does not match the number of arguments you are passing in.

For example, the first `printf` reads:

```
System.out.printf("Total cost %-10d ; quantity %d\n", "ten spaces",5, 120);
```

It's expecting an integer followed by another integer. You are passing in a `String`, an `int`, and another `int`.

In your second `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("%-2d: ", i,  "some text here/n", 1);
```

It's expecting an integer. You are passing in an `int`, a `String`, and another `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the format specifier that corresponds to the first `String` argument on the `printf` method so a `IllegalFormatConversionException` will be thrown

```
System.out.printf("Total cost %s %-10d ; quantity %d\n", "ten spaces", 5, 120);
                              ^
```

Your second `printf` statement will not throw a runtime exception but only the first argument will be displayed. You could do

```
System.out.printf("%-2d: %s %d%n", i,  "some text here/n", 1);
```

Read: [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)